# Solve the following initial value problem for $y'+\frac{1}{|x|}y=x^3$, with $y(-1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a first order inhomogenous linear DE, so I need to use integrating factors right?
But how do I integrate $\frac{1}{|x|}$ to get my integrating factor (it's not differentiable right?)? In my textbook, it says that $e^{\int P(x)dx}$ gives me my integrating factor for first-order LDEs in the form $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$

Comment: Solve separately for x>0 and x<0 first the homogenous equation, than  ad a special solution of the inhomogenous.

Comment: $$y(x)= 
\begin{cases}  
\frac{x^{4}}{3}-\frac{2x}{3}, & x<0 \\[2ex]
\frac{x^{4}}{5}, & x>0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you walk me through your working? I am getting a different solution (see my comment below)

Comment: [Solution x<0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29-1%2F%28x%29*y%28x%29%3Dx%5E3%2C+y%28-1%29%3D1)

[Solution x>0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29%2B1%2F%28x%29*y%28x%29%3Dx%5E3%2C+y%280%29%3D0)